# Assigning data from one column to another (unequal column size) in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel

Hello everyone and many thanks in advance for your help,

[Kit of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ns7.png)

As can be seen above, I have to assign numerical values from column A to column B, so that the number 4193 in column B matches the number 1 in column A each and every time, the number 15 in column B matches the number  2 in column A each and every time, and so on and so forth (this is just a random sample that I've presented as an example, as I'm working with an extremely large dataset). This should have been no big deal, but the thing is that these two columns are of different size (column A is much larger than column B).

I've spent hours and hours trying to do this by myself, as well as browsing forums, but I haven't found any similar question on how to get around this problem. Also, because the dataset I'm working with is extremely large, there is no way I could do this manually.

I'd be enormously grateful if anyone could help me out with this. A gist on how to do this either in R or in Excel would be much appreciated.

Many thanks once again!

P.S. I forgot to add that the main idea would be to have each single number in column B repeated standing side by side with its corresponding number from the column A (as explained previously). I don't know how to do this computationally, but logically, the idea is either to enlarge column B, or to put the numbers into another column, say, column C.

Comment: Please don't post data as images, post the output of `dput(head(dataset, 26))`.

Answer (score 1):

With the following values of `A` and `B`,

```
A <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)

B <- c(4324L, 1459L, 2871L, 3915L)
```

use `rep` with `table(A)` as a `times` argument.

```
rep(B, table(A)[seq_along(B)])
# [1] 4324 4324 4324 4324 4324 4324 4324 4324 1459 1459 1459 1459 1459 1459 1459
#[16] 1459 1459 1459 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 2871 3915 3915
#[31] 3915 3915 3915 3915 3915 3915
```