# How to fill in data in R (data appears incomplete when running the code)

Tags: r

Hello everyone and many thanks in advance for your help,

[Kit of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOPL0.png)

As can be seen above, I have to assign numerical values from column A (ordered real numbers) to column B (unordered real numbers), so that the number 4193 in column B matches the number 1 in column A each and every time, the number 15 in column B matches the number 2 in column A each and every time, and so on and so forth (this is just a random sample that I've presented as an example, as I'm working with an extremely large dataset). This should have been no big deal, but the thing is that these two columns are of different size (column A is much larger than column B).

In total, there are 1.048.575 values in Column A and 10.571 values in Column B.

The data comes contained in Column A comes from one Excel file (X) with 4 variables, and the data in column B comes from another Excel file (Y) with 3 variables.

The expected output should look something like this:

[Sample (not full) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcrwL.png)

I have tried many different codes so far, for instance:

```
A <- X$v1
B <- Y$v1
df <- structure(list(A = c(rep(list(1048575))
), B = c(rep(list(10571)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(-10571L, -1048575L))

Result <- rep(B, table(A)[seq_along(B)])

print(Result)
```

but the additional problem that I've encountered is that I get 959.031 instead of 1.048.575 values (obviously, I need to get 1.048.575 values).

Besides, the output that I get by using the aforementioned code is in the form of a matrix, whereas what I'm looking for is for the data to be ordered in 2 columns.

I am not sure whether the problem stems from the fact that the way I am introducing the data is not correct, or if the issue is with the code, which is not correct.

The closest I have got so far, has been by using this code:

```
Result <- match(A %in% unique(B), B, table(A)[seq_along(B)])
```

It does give me the needed 1.048.575 values, but the output consists of only one repeated number and it is in the form of a matrix, not two columns.

I've been stuck with this issue for days, and any help would indeed be much appreciated.

What I would like to know the most is how to make this work for ALL 1.048.575 values in Column A and 10.571 values in Column B, not just for a sample of, say, 5 or 10 values.

Many thanks once again!

**UPDATE**

```
structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)", "        ans[db] <- sub(\".*\\\\.([^.]+\\\\.)(gz|bz2|xz)$\", \"\\\\1\\\\2\", ", 
"            x[db])", "        ans", "    }", "    names <- c(as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1L]), list)", 
"    if (!is.null(package)) {", "        if (!is.character(package)) ", 
"            stop(\"'package' must be a character string or NULL\")", 
"        if (any(package %in% \"base\")) ", "            warning(\"datasets have been moved from package 'base' to package 'datasets'\")", 
"        if (any(package %in% \"stats\")) ", "            warning(\"datasets have been moved from package 'stats' to package 'datasets'\")", 
"        package[package %in% c(\"base\", \"stats\")] <- \"datasets\"", 
"    }", "    paths <- find.package(package, lib.loc, verbose = verbose)", 
"    if (is.null(lib.loc)) ", "        paths <- c(path.package(package, TRUE), if (!length(package)) getwd(), ", 
"            paths)", "    paths <- unique(normalizePath(paths[file.exists(paths)]))", 
"    paths <- paths[dir.exists(file.path(paths, \"data\"))]", 
"    dataExts <- tools:::.make_file_exts(\"data\")", "    if (length(names) == 0L) {", 
"        db <- matrix(character(), nrow = 0L, ncol = 4L)", "        for (path in paths) {"
), .Dim = c(30L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30"), ""), class = "noquote")
```

Comment: This is a variant of [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884739/assigning-data-from-one-column-to-another-unequal-column-size-in-r-or-excel/71884995#71884995) (if not the same question) and you have 1) not posted data in `dput` format 2) nor told us what's wrong with the answer you got there.

Comment: Dear Rui, I am very grateful for your answer and your proposed solution in my other question. However, what I realised and what makes this question different from the other one is that the output that I get by running the code that you indicated is in the form of a matrix (and not two columns), and besides, the 0s that I have in Column B are omitted for some reason from the final output (I get 900k+ values instead of the needed 1048575 values). I'm really sorry for being repetitive, but I've spent days on this and I just don't know how to get around this issue. Thanks for your kind attention!

Comment: Ok, but you should post a small example of a data set with one or two 0's reproducing the problem. Post `dput(head(data, 30))` in the question, please.

Comment: OK, Rui, I have just done this. Hopefully, this is what you asked me for. By the way, I have to apologise: I thought that the problem was in 0s, but I tried inserting them in first place, and they do appear in the output. However, I am still puzzled by the fact that I get 959031 instead of 1048575 values in the output, and that the output is in a matrix form, instead of it being in columns. Any help would be enormously appreciated. Thank you once again!